# HTML5 Audio autoplay for the first 3 visit/load to website only

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I want this functionality in my website.
The audio should be played automatically for the first 3 visit for a visitor.
For example: If someone visits my website, the audio will be automatically played on each time he loads/refresh the website until his third visit.

```
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay>
    <source src="audio/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: i would think that auto-playing sound would prevent even a 2nd visit...

Comment: Ever heard of [`bgsound`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bgsound)?

Comment: bgsound is not suitable for production sites!

Comment: Seriously, it's just horrible practice to autoplay music on the web. It's downright annoying, and I know there are thousands of web developers behind me when I say it's something you shouldn't do. If someone asked you how to build a bomb, and you knew how, would you tell them how to do it?

Comment: If I would play audio every time visitor loads website that would be annoying. I do not see any wrong in offering audio for just 3 times only ( or just a single time) to a visitor if that audio has specific purpose.

Comment: I can't say I've ever stayed on a website that played background music, let alone re-visited. I don't think it will make much difference.

Comment: it's not for the whole website. Just for a specific page which has good reason behind this autoplay.

Comment: *sigh*...fine. I answered your question. Enjoy your bomb.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the HTML5 `audio` element, and that it does not have the `autoplay` attribute set. This should work:

```
var playCount = localStorage.getItem('playCount') || 0;
if (playCount < 3) {
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
    localStorage.setItem('playCount', playCount + 1);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately! It does not work either!!


<script language=javascript>
        var playCount = localStorage.getItem('playCount') || 0;
if (playCount < 3) {
    document.getElementById('audioElement').play();
    localStorage.setItem('playCount', playCount + 1);
}
</script>




<audio id="audio" controls>
    <source src="audio/moorefund.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/moorefund.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

Comment: Put the script after the audio element. Ideally, you want to load most (if not all) of your scripts right before the end of the `body` element.

Comment: Look for 404 errors in the console. You might not have properly loaded your audio files.

Comment: finally working after little tweak!


document.getElementById('audio').play();

Thank you, Marcus

Comment: No worries. Updated my answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score -1):

u may use html5 session storage , to store the number of visit , then u may disable autoplay

```
if (sessionStorage.visitcount==3) {
var aud = document.getElementById("audio");
aud.autoplay = false;
} 
else {
sessionStorage.visitcount += 1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sessionStorage.visitcount += 1;`

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: `sessionStorage.visitcount` is `undefined` initially, so incrementing it results in `NaN`.

Comment: 1. use localStorage, not sessionStorage. 2. canceling autoplay might happen too late; .play() it the first 3 times instead, and take off the autoplay attrib alltogether.

Comment: It does not work!!!

<script language=javascript>
        if (sessionStorage.visitcount==3) {
            var aud = document.getElementById("audio");
            aud.autoplay = false;
        }
        else {
            sessionStorage.visitcount += 1;
        }
    </script>


<audio id="audio" controls autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="audio/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>